# Do we need [imageai]?

Tags: discussion, tags, clean-up

In the new questions tab this morning I found one question having only the tag [imageai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imageai). This tag didn't have a tag wiki. Looking at the list of questions having this tag, it looks to be frequently used together with [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) (58 questions of 76) and apparently conceptually is related to [artificial-intelligence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/artificial-intelligence) and [machine-learning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/machine-learning).

- At this time there are 76 questions having this tag.
- The [Frequent tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imageai?tab=Frequent) returns 0 results.
- The top answerer based on their score has posted only one answer. Their score is 6.
- The top answerer based on the number of answers has posted 4 answers, but their score is 1.
- In the last 30 days, 100% of questions are unanswered.

As most of the questions are related to the ImageAI python library referred by in [Andrew T's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422808/do-we-need-imageai#comment944188_422808) as confirmed in [Henry Ecker's comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422808/do-we-need-imageai#comment944221_422808), the tag wiki was added to indicate that it should be used for questions about this library.

Considering the above, do you think that is worthwhile to keep [imageai](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imageai)?

---

In the comments there are suggestions to renamed [imageai] to:

- [python-imageai-library]
- [python-imageai]

Comment: Looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58836602/why-am-i-getting-typeerror-in-imageai) is the oldest visible question tagged with it, and I think it's intended for [this specific Python library](https://imageai.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html).

Comment: @AndrewT. Thanks. The user who added the "relevant tag" haven't any post with that tag. Anyway, I think that it's fair to assume what you said about the tag apparently is referring to a Python library. Do we need a tag for that Python library? (what I mean is that is still open what should we do with this tag regarding the wiki)

Comment: We could rename it to [python-imageai-library] or something, and clean up everything else

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine It's similar to [tag:python-imaging-library] (8,867 questions). No idea if that is good or bad.

Comment: It's far too similar, but I have no better disambiguation proposals (beyond yeeting the tag for being about a library with one of the single hardest names to disambiguate, but that isn't a valid reason, sooo)

Comment: I think [python-imageai] is fine; we don't need "-library". We have _many_ other python package tags that are just [python-nameOfPackage]. From what I can tell, it appears the vast majority of posts are already using the tag correctly. There are a few questions that are entirely unclear, and maybe one or two that don't appear to be about that library at all, but for the most part it doesn't appear that the the tag is being _misused_ (any more than any other tags, at least). If it's not being misused as just [imageai], I don't think [python-imageai] is going to make it _less_ clear.

Comment: It looks that no body think, at least during this Sunday,  that is a waste of time adding the tag wiki so I added it. Now, ignoring the two that doesn't appear to be about the library, if it's not being misused as just [imageai], what about if its be kept as is for a while?

Comment: What's the problem with the tag? Only 4 questions have no apparent connection to Python programming (and I'm not an expert at all so they may be about the library).

Comment: @Laurel After this question was posted questions having only [imageai] were retagged (i.e. added [python], [artificial-intelligence]+[machine-learning] and closed as unclear) and the tag wiki was created, so the current problem with the tag apparently is if we want to keep its name as is or rename it.

Comment: But what's the problem with the current tag name? After all, we don't have a "javascript-jquery" tag since there's no ambiguity.

Comment: the concept of "Image AI" seems to be far more prone to become ambiguous than "jquery" ever will, though.